# how to delete an actor in vtk?

Tags: python, vtk

For example,
if i have a cube

(this part of code is from the vtk python example)

```
import vtk

# create a rendering window and renderer
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

# create a renderwindowinteractor
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

# create cube
cube = vtk.vtkCubeSource()

# mapper
cubeMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
cubeMapper.SetInput(cube.GetOutput())

# actor
cubeActor = vtk.vtkActor()
cubeActor.SetMapper(cubeMapper)

# assign actor to the renderer
ren.AddActor(cubeActor)

# enable user interface interactor
iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```

How can i delete this cube actor and add another one?
(This has to be done in order)

Comment: I don't know `vtk`, but the [docs](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderer.html#a5f28085becdef7b5d446598162d23d2b) seem to imply you can do `vtk.RemoveActor`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you tried

```
ren.RemoveActor(cubeActor);
```

?

And after that, you simply add another actor

```
ren.AddActor(anotherActor);
```